# Define $G: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ by the rule $G(x) = 2 − 3x$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Define $G: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ by the rule $G(x) = 2 − 3x$ for all real numbers $x$. Is $G$ onto? Prove or give a counterexample.

this from topic : One-to-One and Onto Functions.

Comment: Yes! Even $G$ is a homeomorphism!

Comment: What does "onto" mean to you? Read your definition. That will likely tell you exactly what you need to do to give a proof, or give you a hint on where to start looking for a coutnerexample.

Comment: @ChinnapparajR There are no topologies involved here, so the function cannot be called a homeomorphism. You could call it an isomorphism in the category of sets.

Comment: @drhab:  I mean If one can consider $G$ is a function on a usual metric  space $\Bbb{R}$ then it is a homeomorphism.

Comment: @ChinnapparajR Yes, but if domain is equipped with usual topology and codomain with another then it is *not* a homeomorphism. What is the use of remarks as: "if $\cdots$ then $\cdots$", here?

Comment: @ChinnapparajR Just aside: I had a look at your profile. Did Halmos really say that? I strongly disagree with him.

Comment: I don't care anything about other's opinion about Halmos quote!

Comment: That supposed quote by Halmos seems to be false. I can't find it among his other quotes.

Comment: @ChinnapparajR As you can see by the comment of DonAntonio there are doubts about the quote. IMO you should feel obliged to check out the authenticity and give some reference. If it is not a quote of him then you are somehow polluting his name.

Comment: @drhab: sorry for my previous comment! But I took that quote in his auto mathography , namely, "I Want to be a Mathematician "

Comment: @ChinnapparajR Ego te absolvo. Thanks for the reference.

Answer (score 2):

If $y_0 \in \mathbb R$, is there some $x_0 \in \mathbb R$ such that $2-3x_0=y_0$ ?

If yes, then $G$ is onto, if no, then $G$ is not onto.